# Restify how to create a filter to capture requests and responses and log

Tags: node.js, filter, interceptor, restify

In my restify server I have a route that I want to add a filter to. The way this would work in Express (this does work in Express) is the `response.on` would add my handler as the callback. Then before the response is returned to the requestor my handler would be called. This is not the behavior I am seeing in Restify. My guess is I am not registering my handler to the event machine properly.

```
restifyServer.get({ path: "/api/v1/readings", version: ["1.0.0"]}, Reading.getReadings);
```

I add a handler:

```
function zipkinTracing(request, response, next){
  // handle the callback request and record the trace
  var trace = zipkin.getTraceFromRequest(request, "ids-api", {address: config.externalIP, port: 80});

  if (trace){
    zipkin.sendAnnotationReceive(trace);
    zipkin.sendAnnotation(trace, 'request.headers',JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    trace.parentSpanId = trace.spanId;
    zipkin.sendAnnotation(trace, 'http.uri', request.url);

    var queryObj = urlLib.parse(request.url, true).query;
    Object.keys(queryObj).forEach( function(key){
      zipkin.sendAnnotation(trace, key, queryObj[key]);
    });
    request.zipkinTrace = trace;
  }

  response.on('after', function(request, response, route, error){
     var t = request.zipkinTrace;
     if (t) {
       zipkin.sendAnnotation(t, 'http.response.code',response.code);
       zipkin.sendAnnotationSend(t);
    }
  });

  return next();
}
```

Now my routes look like this:

```
restifyServer.use(zipkinTracing);
restifyServer.get({ path: "/api/v1/readings", version: ["1.0.0"]}, Reading.getReadings);
```

The problem is the `response.on('after',` is never fired. What am I doing wrong here?

Reading.getReadings looks like this:

```
makeHttpQuery(request, response, function(error, message) {
   ....
   response.send(message['data']['data']);
   return next();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. In order to create a true filter I registered the handler function to the `response.on('finish', handler)` as you would do in Express. The alternate solution would be to place

```
restifyServer.on('after',  function(request, response){
  var t = request.zipkinTrace;
  if (t) {
    zipkin.sendAnnotation(t, 'http.response.code',response.code);
    zipkin.sendAnnotationSend(t);
  }
});
```

after the route to be filtered. I prefer the `response.on('finish', handler)`. Any other solutions or interesting ways to create a filter for requests and responses?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add multiple handlers to the request. One handler will finish and pass on the the next one, much like a filter.

See: http://restify.com/#routing